# exist some errors when i use MegaDetector

Tags: module

After installing it according to its installation environment requirements, run python detection\run_detector.py "c:\megdetector\md_v5a.0.0.pt" --image_file "some_image_file.jpg " --threshold 0.1, the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'md_visualization', do you have a solution?

I searched a lot in the documentation but didn't find the relevant information I wanted. I hope to find out where this module is and how to install it

Comment: give `pip install torchvision` a try

Answer (score 0):

md_visualization is a folder within the MegaDetector repo; if you are using the [MegaDetector setup instructions](https://github.com/agentmorris/MegaDetector/blob/main/megadetector.md#using-the-model), you're asked to make sure the MegaDetector folder (i.e., the folder to which you checked out the MegaDetector repo) is in your PYTHONPATH environment variable, like this:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;c:\git\MegaDetector;c:\git\yolov5
```

Any chance you skipped that step?  If you have added the right folder to your PYTHONPATH and you're still getting this error, please [file an issue](https://github.com/agentmorris/MegaDetector/issues).